# Adding Search Text-Box in GridView Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

The first rows  in my gridview are blank rows and these blank rows are used for searching values in my gridview.  I am adding a blank row on every column but i don't want to add any blank row on the first column which is the ID for my data. I only want add the blank rows starting from the 2nd column.  How can i do this?
here is my code behind:

```
protected void OnDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);
    for (int i = 0; i < GV_EditProject.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        TableHeaderCell cell = new TableHeaderCell();
        TextBox txtSearch = new TextBox();
        txtSearch.Attributes["placeholder"] = GV_Test.Columns[i].HeaderText;
        txtSearch.CssClass = "search_textbox";
        cell.Controls.Add(txtSearch);
        row.Controls.Add(cell);
    }
    GV_Test.HeaderRow.Parent.Controls.AddAt(1, row);
}
```

here is my aspx file

```
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" ItemStyle-Width="5">
        <ItemStyle Width="5px" />
    </asp:BoundField>
```

Comment: If you are using template fields, it is easier to add textboxes in the markup. `HeaderTemplate` could be a good place  to add search TextBox.

Comment: i am using bound field,  can you show me how to add the header-template?

Comment: i just added the aspx code for my gridview in which i am using bound field.  please look at my initial post.  thanks

Comment: You can convert those boundfields to template field to add HeaderTemplate. See the example below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to use `TemplateField` for the columns with search textbox at header. For example, I have added one to "Comments" below :

```
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" ItemStyle-Width="5">
        <ItemStyle Width="5px" />
    </asp:BoundField>

    <%-- This bound field is converted to Template Field --%>
    <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="COMMENTS" HeaderText="COMMENTS" ItemStyle-Width="5">
        <ItemStyle Width="5px" />
    </asp:BoundField>--%>

    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="150px" HeaderText="COMMENTS">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblComm" runat="server" Text ='<%# Eval("COMMENTS")%>' ></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchComment" runat="server" CssClass="search_textbox" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
        </HeaderTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```